# How does mint-oracle work in nft games

Tags: oracles, price, mint

I'm new to this world of smart contracts, and I have some doubts about how nft games **mint-oracle** works.

Basically it sets the prices of game items based on a currency. example: **USD**.

My doubt is whether this system has to be done along with the contract or I can do it from outside using an example api to coingecko.

I made a code that is working perfect. but I don't know if this is the best way.

```
const CoinGeckoClient = new CoinGecko();

//Token CoinGecko Ids
const token_ids = 'monster-grand-prix-token'; //Token Example get: https://www.coingecko.com/pt/moedas/monster-grand-prix-token
const token_name = 'SurvivalCrypto'; //Token Name Example
const vs_currencies = 'usd'; //fix in USD
let paramsObject = {ids: token_ids, vs_currencies: vs_currencies, include_24hr_vol: false, include_last_updated_at: true, include_market_cap:false  }

let token = [];
async function tokenPrice() {
    token = [];
    let data = await CoinGeckoClient.simple.price(paramsObject);
    token = data.data[token_ids];
}

var tokenPrice = token.usd; //Prince 1 token in USD

//Price in USD
var boxCharacterPrice = 15; // $15 USD
var boxCampPrice = 20; // $20 USD

//Mint Prices
var boxCharacterTokenQty = 1 / (tokenPrice / boxCharacterPrice); //i need **x** token to buy this ex: 0.1 token
var boxCampTokenQty = 1 / (tokenPrice / boxCampPrice); i need **x** token to buy this ex: 0.5 token
```

[image]